# Using typeid keyword C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a code and I wanna display the class type of array pointer using typeid keyword, but when I'm writing `cout <<typeid (Food[1]);`the compilation error! Error: no operator "<<"matches these operands ,operand type are:std::ostream <

```
class food{
public:
    string getkind(){
        return kind;
    }
    virtual void setkind(){
    kind = "Apple";
    }
    // complete the set functions
private:
    string  kind;

};
int main()
{
    food *Food[3];
    derived1 obj1;
    derived2 obj2;
    derived3 obj3;
    Food[0]=&obj1;
    Food[1] = &obj2;
    Food[2] = &obj3;
    cout << typeid (food[1]);//Error ! Why? 


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compilation error? Show it please.

Comment: You need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a complete error message.

Comment: Please provide the error message and the code snippet that gives you the compilation error, this way it is not possible to help

Comment: Also compiler name and command-line used to compile the code... It's likely that you need to enable RTTI to make this work.

Comment: Food is object from the class type of food , `food *Food[3];`

Comment: @Khan: please do as others have already recommended. provide a minimal but complete example that readers can compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Error: no operator "<<"matches these operands ,operand type are:std::ostream <<const type_info

Comment: So, you can't print a `type_info` value, because there is no defined output pattern for that...

Comment: Try `std::cout << typeid(Food[1]).name();`

Answer (score 1):

#### MCVE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class X {};

int main() {
    std::cout << typeid(X) << "\n";
}
```

#### Error messages:

```
foo.cc:7:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const std::type_info')
    std::cout << typeid(X) << "\n";
    ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~
```

#### Fix:

`typeid(X)` returns a [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) object. It has a very usefully named method called `name`.

#### Better code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class X {};

int main() {
    std::cout << typeid(X).name() << "\n";
}
```

#### Better Output (Implementation defined):

```
1X
```